# Taylor series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Is there a sequence of rational numbers $a_0, a_1, \dotsc$ such that $\sum\limits_{i\geq 0}a_i x^i$ converges absolutely to $2^x$ for every $x\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

You can construct such a series of the form

$$ 1 + \sum_{i=0}^\infty (a_i + b_i x)  \left( \frac{x^2}{(i+1)^2}\right)^{e_i} \prod_{j=-i}^i (x-j) $$

for some sequence $a_i, b_i$ of rational numbers and some sequence $e_i$ of natural numbers (converging to $\infty$.)

This certainly defines a power series with rational coefficients since the $i$th term is divisible by $x^{2 e_i}$ and $e_i$ goes to $\infty$, so the coefficient of each power of $x$ is a finite sum of rational numbers.

The $\prod(x-j)$ term ensures that the $i$th term vanishes at every integer from $-i$ to $i$. Thus the function has the value $2^x$ at $x=i+1$ and $x=-i-1$ if and only if the sum of the first $i$ terms has the value $2^x$ at those points. For any values of $a_1,\dots, a_{i-1}, b_1,\dots, b_{i-1}, e_1,\dots, e_{i-1}$, there is a unique rational $a_i,b_i$ which ensures this power series takes the correct value at these $x$. (The denominator $i+1$ is so that the value of $e_i$ does not affect this.)

Now we can choose $e_i$ sufficiently large depending on $a_1,\dots, a_{i-1}, b_1,\dots, b_{i-1}, e_1,\dots, e_{i-1},a_i,b_i$ so that the version of the $i$th term with absolute values everywhere

$$(|a_i| + |b_i| |x|)  \left( \frac{|x|^2}{(i+1)^2}\right)^{e_i} \prod_{j=-i}^i (|x|+|j|) $$
is as small as desired at the points $-i,\dots, i$. For example, we can ensure it is at most $2^{-i}$.

Having done this, the series is certainly absolutely convergent at all integer points (and thus at all points), because all but finitely many of the terms have absolute value at most $2^{-i}$ at any given point.

Choosing $a_i,b_i,e_i$ according to this rubric, our series satisfies all the desiderata.

Comment: This reminds me of the construction (of Mahler?) of a power series $f(x)\in\mathbb Q[[x]]$ that is absolutely convergent on $\mathbb R$, is transcendental over $\mathbb R(x)$, and satisfies $f(\mathbb Q)\subset\mathbb Q$. Not quite the same problem, since here you want to specify the values at the integers, but my recollection is that the construction is a similar sum of products so that at any rational $x$, all but finitely many terms in the sum vanish.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Cool! This answer is a composite of a couple tricks I've learned at different points in my mathematical career - probably all on MO. It's very possible that there is some chain of "X learned this trick from Y" links that connects it to Mahler.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. We construct inductively a sequence $b_0,b_1,\ldots$ of real numbers such that $|b_k|\leqslant 1/k!$ and all coefficients of the entire function
$$
2^z+(b_0+b_1z+\ldots)\sin \pi z
$$
are rational. If $b_0,\ldots,b_{m-1}$ are already defined and the coefficients of $1,z,z^2,\ldots,z^m$ are rational, we may choose appropriate $b_m$ so that the coefficient of $z^{m+1}$ (which is $\pi b_m$ plus something known) is rational.

Comment: This answer shows, in addition, that you can replace $2^x$ with the values of any entire function, and my answer shows, in addition, that you can replace $2^x$ with any rational sequence. Combining the ideas, it's not hard to show that you can replace $2^x$ with an arbitrary real-valued function.

Comment: @WillSawin moreover, there exists an entire function taking prescribed values at any sequence of points converging to infinity https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1529860/166817